# Difference between DxO's Nik Collection 3 and DxO PhotoLab 3?

Tags: post-processing, photoshop

Can someone tell me the difference between DxO's [Nik Collection 3](https://nikcollection.dxo.com/) and [DxO PhotoLab 3](https://www.dxo.com/dxo-photolab/)?  They seem so similar but I can't find any comparison to help me decide.

(If this is somehow the wrong sort of question to post here, please accept my apologies and help me find the appropriate forum.  Thanks)

Answer (score 2):

DxO PhotoLab is a standalone program, which you can use to 'develop' RAW files and edit your photos.
The Nik Collection 3  is a set of plugins for Adobe Lightroom and Photoshop, so you need to have the Adobe Software to use the Nik Collection.

Comment: So does this mean that the Nik Collection is used only after Lr or Ps has used Adobe Camera Raw to process the image?

Comment: sorry, I'm not familiar with the CR/LR/PS workflow. I'm using PhotoLab 3.3.